# How to show that sigma algebras generated by different RV are the same

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Consider the following Argument:

When, for random variables $X$ and $Y$, $Y=f(X)$ with $f$ a strictly monotonic function, we have $\sigma(X)=\sigma(Y)$. The argument is easy to show by inverting $f$ and going back and forth between the events in $\sigma(X)$ and $\sigma(Y)$ to show the equality.

I am wondering if anyone is aware of a similar result for scenarios where $Y=f(X,Z)$, for some other random variable $Z$. I'm not sure because "inverting" the function won't work. If not, what would be useful results to show that $\sigma(Y)=\sigma(X,Z)$?